# Pedestrian approach to irreducible representations of the orthogonal group

Tags: group-theory, reference-request, representation-theory, book-recommendation

Where can I find a simple minded introduction to the theory of the irreducible representations (over the reals) of the orthogonal group $O(N)$, mentioning the relation to traceless tensors and to the Brauer algebra, one that could be understood by an undergraduate, or a physicist?